# Fewer people in the streets vs. fewer people on the streets

Tags: phrase-choice

What's the correct or at least the most common option?

Someone told me that "in the streets" means being literately *in the middle of the street.*

On the streets means *on the sides of the street.*

However, "fewer people in the streets" and "fewer people on the streets" have more or less the same numbers of results on Google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I am on the street" or "I am in the street"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129892/i-am-on-the-street-or-i-am-in-the-street)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [to come out {on to | to | on | into | in} the streets.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46578/to-come-out-on-to-to-on-into-in-the-streets) That one's definitely a more ***precise*** duplicate for the usage being queried here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that "in the street" literally means being in the road when it refers to a *person* or any other thing that perhaps shouldn't be there. Strangely, when it's a *car* or another vehicle, that car is "on the street / road".

"On the street" can mean a number of things. For example, a house or other building *on* a street means it is built just off the street. *People* "on the street" could refer to pedestrians walking on the pavement/sidewalk or people living on a particular named street, but it can also idiomatically mean people living homeless, and people involved in street crime.

Comment: So it's better so say, "There are fewer people on the streets these days?"